# Need mysql results even if all parameters are not met

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm using my client's mysql database. My client has form search fields: voltage, power, size, material and length. They want the visitor to enter any combination of these and get some results. I've tried using AND and we get no results, I tried using OR and got all the records no matter what. What am I missing? The form data is turned into $POST_variables like $pvoltage. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
WHERE 
(voltage = '$pvoltage' AND power_kw = '$ppower' AND size LIKE '$psize%' AND
material = '$pmat' AND immers_length LIKE '$plength%')
```

Also tried it with OR - gave me everything instead of just the results where there was data. This gives me nothing.

Comment: *and get some results* WHAT results? rows where at least one value is found? two of them at least? two strictly? all values? something else?

Comment: **AND** is correct. Please post your table schema, sample data and the query

Comment: I can't post all the schema - too long code. Multiple tables and fields joined. The result I want is this....

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me in the WHERE statement:

```
IF('$pvoltage' ='',voltage LIKE '%',voltage LIKE '$pvoltage')
```